# When I deploy Prometheus and the Nginx exporter using Docker Compose, I am unable to scrape the metrics

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, prometheus

I'm only trying to scrape Prometheus metrics on my localhost for testing purposes.

When I access http://localhost:9113/metrics, I can retrieve the metrics, and when I go to Prometheus interface at http://localhost:9090/targets, the target section shows the endpoint as http://nginx-prometheus-exporter:9113/metrics. However, when I visit this link, there are no metrics available, causing Prometheus to be unable to scrape the metrics.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - nginx-prometheus-network

  nginx-prometheus-exporter:
    image: nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:0.10.0
    ports:
      - 9113:9113
    command: -nginx.scrape-uri=http://nginx:80/stub_status
    networks:
      - nginx-prometheus-network

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    networks:
      - nginx-prometheus-network

networks:
  nginx-prometheus-network:
```

here is my nginx.conf

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /stub_status {
            stub_status;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my prometheus.yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'nginx'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['nginx-prometheus-exporter:9113']
```

Comment: I don't understand problem at hand. Based on posted configs Prometheus should scrape metrics correctly. Do you see nginx exporter as up in list of targets?

Comment: "However, when I visit this link, ..." for you and for Prometheus it's different address. You should go through localhost, since you are outside of docker. Prometheus can go through container name since it's included into the same docker network.

Comment: Can you provide sample code to solve the problem?

Comment: What problem? And what code do you expect, if this is clearly not programming problem (whatever this problem is)?